# Selecting sets with the top 10% of combined votes among objects

Tags: mysql

For some background, I previously asked about [retrieving sets with highest number of combined votes among objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741579/retrieving-sets-with-highest-number-of-combined-votes-among-objects). That works great for getting the top 25, but now I would like to get the top 10%, ordered by rankset's timestamp. Here are the tables in question:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rankset` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL ,
  `rankset` BIGINT NOT NULL ,
  `image` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `description` VARCHAR(140) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`vote` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `value` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `item` BIGINT NOT NULL ,
  `user` BIGINT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

I'd list what I've tried so far, but I honestly don't even know where to begin with this one. Here's the SQL fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe315/9

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4474389/97513, He generates a column for the ranking of his items, use a `WHERE` clause that uses `rank <= (SELECT COUNT(1) / 10 FROM rankset)` to identify the top 10%

Comment: I put together an SQL fiddle to demonstrate: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe315/21 - Here's another with more results so you can see it scales up when you add more rows: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a02ea/1

Comment: That looks like what I want. Want to put that in an answer so I can choose it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4474389/97513, He generates a column for the ranking of his items, use a WHERE clause that uses `rank <= (SELECT COUNT(1) / 10 FROM rankset)` to identify the top 10%.

I put together an SQL fiddle to demonstrate: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe315/21 - Here's another with more results so you can see it scales up when you add more rows: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a02ea/1

SQL Used:

```
SET @rn := 0;

SELECT (@rn:=@rn+1) AS rank, q.*
FROM (
   SELECT rankset.*, COALESCE(COUNT(vote.id), 0) AS votes 
   FROM rankset, vote, item 
   WHERE item.rankset = rankset.id  
          AND vote.item = item.id 
   GROUP BY rankset.id
   ORDER BY votes DESC
) q
WHERE
    @rn <= (SELECT COUNT(1)/10 FROM rankset);
```